# Do arcane Discoveries count as feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

A Wizard can use his feats to learn [Arcane Discoveries](http://archivesofnethys.com/WizardArcaneDiscoveries.aspx).
Do they count as feats for effects that modify feats like [spell perfection](http://archivesofnethys.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Perfection) which doubles the numerical bonuses applied to a spell by feats.

I can not access the d20pfsrd site from this computer so I used archives of Nethys, once more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No.

If they were feats, [it would say so](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats#TOC-Types-of-Feats). But instead, it says the opposite, that they can be learned instead of feats:

> A wizard can learn an arcane discovery in place of a regular feat or wizard bonus feat.

### Arcane discoveries are class abilities.

Answer (score 2):

Arcane discoveries are wizard-exclusive. They are not unlike archetypes (you could call them minor archetypes or alternate class features) in which they replace a bonus feat from the wizard progression, **OR** a regular feat the wizard character would receive from leveling.

Note that a discovery cannot be gained with a bonus feat from another source if multiclassing.

Since it does not says anything, you could dip 1 level of wizard and unlock the discoveries to purchase with level advancement feats.

Comment: A *fighter bonus feat* is a bad example, as those only allow **Combat Feats**.

Comment: removed the example about fighter feats. lets get generic. thanks @ShadowKras